# Creating multiple forms inside a Xform document and traveling between them sequentially and conditionally.

Tags: forms, user-interface, web, xforms

I'm trying to create a form builder that is based on XForms 2.0 standards.
I need to support the feature of creating multiple forms/surveys and connecting them. Allowing the end user developer to control the flow of the travel... Both sequentially and conditionally. Conditionally meaning to make the survey/forms (Some form would not be shown to the user depending on the user input) I'm struggling to find a logical solution to use while creating the XForm 2.0 model. Anyone have some ideas i can use or anything i missed ?

Comment: Just curious: did one of the solutions suggested in my previous message work for you?

Comment: No sadly, i wasn't interested in the functional level of the form generation rather on the existing specifications on how can i extend upon it. In other words i wasn't interested in the authoring tool and how to to present it once the person wanted to fill it but rather on the forms level

Comment: I am not following: you're saying "I wasn't interested in […] but rather on the forms level". What do you mean by "on the forms level"? Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to do.

Comment: My question was regarding specifications wise rather than authoring tool, w3c xforms specifications

Comment: Got it, then the answer is pretty simple: the way forms are sequenced isn't covered by the XForms specification. (In the same, say, that the way HTML forms are sequenced isn't covered by the HTML specification.)

Answer (score 1):

How forms are sequenced isn't covered by the XForms specification. In Orbeon Forms specifically, there are 2 ways to handle the sequencing of distinct forms:

- Implement those forms in a single form in Form Builder, and rely on the [wizard view](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/features/wizard-view) to have only one part of the large form shown at any given point in time.
- Create separate forms in Form Builder, and write logic that runs when users submit every single form to determine what the "next form" is. This is done in a [process tied to a button](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes).